# Sealed type parameter

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I was wondering if it would be possible to use Scala macros to generate something equivalent to the following:

```
sealed type Foo
type Bar <: Foo
type Baz <: Foo
```

Then the following expression would be recognized as not being exhaustive

```
(foo: Foo) match {
  case bar: Bar => ???
}
```

Looking at the comments in [`PatternMatching.scala`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/transform/patmat/PatternMatching.scala), it looks like there could be a way to communicate those constraints to the typechecker.

Comment: `sealed type` isn't legal syntax, did you mean `sealed class`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`type Bar <: Foo` defines an abstract type member, it would be perfectly legal for it to be given the concrete definition `type Bar = Foo`, in which case the match would be exhaustive. The compiler would need the code for the match and the code giving the concrete definition to `Bar` to compare to decide if the match was exhaustive. Because these could be in separate classes/traits, compiled separately from each other, this is not possible. Suppose a superclass has the abstract definition and is compiled, then a subclass with the concrete definition is compiled, then the match statement is added in the superclass and compiled. The compiler has no idea that the subclass exists when compiling the new definition of the superclass, so it has no way of knowing that the match isn't exhaustive.

Comment: You are right, there are not enough constraints on the types. As your answer is totally valid given the current question, I am happy to accept it and I will create a new question with more context.