# Pattern matching on abstract types with a fold

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, scala-macros

This is a follow-up to a [previous question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23925763/sealed-type-parameter/23926198) which was far from being complete. All the code that follows compiles and run fine in the Scala console.

Consider the following abstract data type, along with the operations it must support as a typeclass:

```
trait SIG {
  type XOrY
  type X <: XOrY
  type Y <: XOrY
}

trait SIGOps[Sig <: SIG] {
  def makeX(s: String): Sig#X
  def makeY(i: Int): Sig#Y
  // the disjunction is enforced with that fold
  def fold[T](xy: Sig#XOrY)(isX: String => T, isY: Int => T): T
  // the following is for convenience, as we want to mimick case classes
  object X {
    def apply(s: String): Sig#X = makeX(s)
    def unapply(xy: Sig#XOrY): Option[String] = fold(xy)(s => Some(s), i => None)
  }
  object Y {
    def apply(i: Int): Sig#Y = makeY(i)
    def unapply(xy: Sig#XOrY): Option[Int] = fold(xy)(s => None, i => Some(i))
  }
}
```

And now, here is a possible implementation for the signature. The typeclass instance is in the companion object for easy discovery.

```
trait EitherSig extends SIG {
  type XOrY = scala.util.Either[String, Int]
  type X = scala.util.Left[String, Int]
  type Y = scala.util.Right[String, Int]
}

object EitherSig {

  implicit object EitherSIGOps extends SIGOps[EitherSig] {
    def makeX(s: String): EitherSig#X = scala.util.Left[String, Int](s)
    def makeY(i: Int): EitherSig#Y = scala.util.Right[String, Int](i)
    def fold[T](xy: EitherSig#XOrY)(isX: String => T, isY: Int => T): T = xy match {
      case Left(s) => isX(s)
      case Right(s) => isY(s)
    }
  }

}
```

And finally, here is how one can write code that depends on the abstract signature.

```
class Example[Sig <: SIG](implicit ops: SIGOps[Sig]) {
  import ops._
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val xy: Sig#XOrY = X("foo")
    xy match {
      case X(s) => println("X: "+s)
      // Scala does not see that the pattern matching is not exhaustive if when I comment the following line
      // case Y(i) => println("Y: "+i)
    }
  }
}

object ConcreteExample extends Example[EitherSig]
```

And it works as expected:

```
scala> ConcreteExample.main(Array())
X: foo
```

The question is the following: how can I teach Scala to recognize when the pattern matching is not exhaustive as above?

There might be [a way to communicate this information to the typechecker](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/transform/patmat/PatternMatching.scala#L18) but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jason Zaugg gave [an answer on Twitter](https://twitter.com/retronym/status/472077761834909696):

> [...] we don't have an extension point for that. Only sealed hierarchies are considered.

Travis Brown [proposed](https://twitter.com/travisbrown/status/472079474289573888) to `Write a matchExhaustive macro that inspects the partial function` but doesn't think that it's `Worth the trouble when you've got the fold`.

So no real solution for that question for now.